# Django REST framework - MultiSelectField - TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-multiselectfield

I'm trying to make a multi-choice rest api with `Django REST framework` and `django-multiselectfield`.

Currently inside the model I have:

```
ANIMAL = (
    ('dog', 'Dog'),
    ('cat', 'Cat'),
)

class MyForm(models.Model):
    ...
    animals = MultiSelectField(choices=ANIMAL)
```

and in my serializer I have:

```
class MyFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyForm
        fields = (..., 'animals')

    animals = fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ANIMAL)
```

When I'm trying to POST into the api using this kind of body:

```
{
    ...
    "animals": ["cat"],
    ...
}
```

I get an error: `TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\mysite\myserver\myform\views.py", line 15, in angels_add
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 558, in __init__
    data = json.dumps(data, cls=encoder, **json_dumps_params)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 104, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable
```

Though, the form is submitted and I can see the entire data in the admin panel **succesfully** (?).

I'm using the following versions:

- Django==2.2.1
- djangorestframework==3.9.3
- django-multiselectfield==0.1.8

any idea why I get this exception?

also, I can switch from multiselectfield to another technology if something else would work and will allow me to add multiple choice fields which I can filter later from the admin panel

```
class MyFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        'animals',
        ...
    )
```

I've read about `ArrayField`, but I'm not happy with a solution that fit only one kind of db (postgres) as I might use another.

Thanks in advance,

Etay.

Comment: `fields.MultipleChoiceField` ? Where that comes from?

Comment: @JPG https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/

Comment: What would be the result if you remove the `animal` field from serializer?

Comment: @JPG validation error: `{ "animals": ["\"['cat']\" is not a valid choice."]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L1471),  the **`to_representation()`** method of **`MultipleChoiceField`** returns data as ***`set`***

Create a custom MultipleChoiceField class and use it in your serializer

```
class CustomMultipleChoiceField(fields.MultipleChoiceField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return list(super().to_representation(value))
```

```
class MyFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyForm
        fields = (..., 'animals')

    animals = CustomMultipleChoiceField(choices=ANIMAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

JPG's solution might work in some cases, but is not really rugged. (also depends on your use case)

A more low level way of solving this, is by extending the `JSONEncoder` or even better `DjangoJSONEncoder` (which is already extended) and using it. This way, you only have to implement it ones.

```
class CustomJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    """
    Custom encoder that also supports `set`, since we require this for
    saving the `MultipleChoiceField`.
    """

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, set):
            return list(obj)
        return super().default(obj)
```